# How prove that $fg$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ be the extended real line (i.e. including $\{\pm \infty\}$). If  $f,g : X \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ are measurable then $f g$ is measurable (where $0 \cdot (\pm \infty)=0$).

Note that $h=fg$ is measurable iff $h^{-1}(\{+\infty\}), h^{-1}(\{-\infty\})$ is measurable and $h$ is measurable on $h^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$. 
I try to use this lemma. But How to prove that? Clearly, $f^{-1}(\{+\infty\}), f^{-1}(\{-\infty\})$ are measurable but how about $g^{-1}f^{-1}(\{+\infty\}), g^{-1}f^{-1}(\{-\infty\})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse image is not $f^{-1}g^{-1}$, this is misleading.

Rather, we have a long formula:
\begin{align*}
& h^{-1}(\infty)\\
&=\{x\in X: f(x)g(x)=\infty\}\\
&=\{x\in X: f(x)\in\mathbb{R}^{+}, g(x)=\infty\}\cup\{x\in X: f(x)=\infty, g(x)\in\mathbb{R}^{+}\}\\
&~~~~~~~~\cup\{x\in X: f(x)=\infty, g(x)=\infty\}\cup\{x\in X: f(x)\in\mathbb{R}^{-}, g(x)=-\infty\}\\
&~~~~~~~~\cup\{x\in X: f(x)=-\infty, g(x)=-\infty\}\cup\{x\in X: g(x)\in\mathbb{R}^{-}, f(x)=-\infty\}\\
&=[f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^{+})\cap g^{-1}(\infty)]\cup[f^{-1}(\infty)\cap g^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^{+})]\\
&~~~~~~~~\cup[f^{-1}(\infty)\cap g^{-1}(\infty)]\cdots
\end{align*}
where $\mathbb{R}^{+}=(0,\infty)$, $\mathbb{R}^{-}=(-\infty,0)$, each of them is measurable.